# how to find version number of Julia? Is there a ver() command?

Tags: julia

I installed Julia studio 0.4.4, and found it does not support multi-line comments `#=...=#` so I wanted to find what version of Julia it is running.

In Matlab one types the command [ver](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ver.html) which not only shows the version number of matlab, but also the version numbers of all toolboxes installed.

I googled for sometime, but not able to find similar command for Julia. Is there such a command for Julia?

```
julia> Version
ErrorException("Version not defined")
julia> ver
ErrorException("ver not defined")
julia> ver()
ErrorException("ver not defined")
julia> Version()
ErrorException("Version not defined")
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use the `versioninfo` command:

From the [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/InteractiveUtils/#InteractiveUtils.versioninfo):

```
versioninfo([verbose::Bool])

    Print information about the version of Julia in use. If the verbose argument 
    is true, detailed system information is shown as well.
```

Comment: There's also the `VERSION` constant which simply contains the version number.

Comment: Inside julia prompt, `versioninfo()` will get you version info.

Answer (score 51):

Just entering out the constant `VERSION` would also display the version number.

```
julia> VERSION
v"0.4.0"
```

Comment: One related usage of this variable to make a section of code for a specific version or range of versions: `@static if VERSION >= v"0.7" .......  end`

Answer (score 4):

If you are using windows,you can use **julia -version** of the cmd command

Comment: what if you have multiple versions installed?